# Laravel not Return controller variable error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, controller

i`m going to draw a chart and also fetch data in a same view.so that this is the controller .

```
public function division_details()
{

     $items = registerdetails::whereDate('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))->whereDate('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();

  $chart = Charts::database(registerdetails::whereDate('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))->whereDate('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))->get(), 'bar', 'highcharts')
        ->title("Active Trainne Working Divisions")
        ->responsive(false)
        ->Width(0)
        ->groupBy('trainee_division');
    return view('registeredusers.divisiondetails', compact('items'),['chart' => $chart]);
}
```

so that i called that items variable in a view so that from this controller items variable not returning so that um getting this error in called view.[image]

can anyone suggest me the correct code correction.

Comment: Just do `compact('items', 'chart')` or do ` ['chart' => $chart, 'items' => items]`. pick one.

Comment: Both not working bro

Comment: The name of the view, `registeredusers.divisiondetails`, does not match the name of the view that is throwing the error, `registeredusers.adminidivisiondetails`.

Comment: bro ur correct in first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your view doesn't understand one variable.
This means that eather there is nothing to return so $items doesnt exist.

Or Something wrong with the controller. Maybe as @Ohgodwhy is correct and you only need to do is that.

`return view('registeredusers.divisiondetails', compact('items','chart'));`

Also, go to that view file and check out the line 43 to see what you use. Moreover, if you can't solve it. try to return only the $items variable.

Comment: No it gives Undefined variable: chart bro ,y is that?

Comment: So $items doesn't exist ?

Comment: Also, you model must to be that: registerdetails.